Problem with Dirac-Bergmann algorithm
This is from Lemos, Analytical Mechanics, Problem 8.24.
Consider the Lagrangian
$$L = (\dot{y}- z)(\dot{x} - y).$$
I found the Lagrangian equations of motion to be
$$\ddot{y} = \dot{z},$$
$$\ddot{x} = z$$
$$\dot{x} = y$$
Now the question is to find the same with the Dirac Bergmann algorithm. From the consistency equation, I get the primary constraint
$$p_z \approx 0.$$
I also get the Hamiltonian
$$H = p_x p_y + y p_x + z p_y,$$
and I get as secondary constraints $p_y\approx 0$ and $p_x\approx 0$. I do not get anymore constraints. So is it right to get than the total Hamiltonian:
$$H_T = p_x p_y + y p_x + z p_y + \lambda p_x + \mu p_y + \nu p_z,$$
but this gets me the Hamiltonian equations as
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \dot{x} & = & = p_y + y + \lambda\\
    \dot{y} & = & p_x + z + \mu\\
    \dot{z} & = & \nu\\
    \dot{p}_x & = & 0\\
    \dot{p}_y & = & -p_x\\
    \dot{p}_z & = & -p_y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Where I think $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are arbitrary functions of time? I don't see how this gets me the aforementioned solutions of the Lagrangian equations.

Did you try to apply the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Where exactly are you stuck? What exactly do you want to show? If you want to show that these two sets of equations are equivalent, you need to actually compute and compare their solutions, or make the arbitrary functions of time explicit in the first set of equations.
